# Format specifies 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'char*'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, colors, uicolor

I am trying to print the R, G and B value to a label, however It wont print correctly to the label, it just prints the R value with a random set of numbers each time. The error is **"Format specifies 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'char*'**

I am new to ios development so help would be appreciated.

```
  NSLog(@"RGB Value of each pixel:");
  UInt32 * currentPixel = pixels;
  for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      UInt32 color = *currentPixel;

        printf("(R=%3.0u, G=%3.0u, B=%3.0u) ", R(color), G(color), B(color));

        ERROR HERE >>  _resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R= %3.0u", "G= 3.0u", "B= 3.0u", R(color), G(color), B(color)];


        currentPixel++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

This gets the pixels of the image

```
  CGImageRef inputCGImage = [image CGImage];
  NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
  NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);

  NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
  NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
  NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

  UInt32 * pixels;
  pixels = (UInt32 *) calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32));

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height,
                                               bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                               kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), inputCGImage);

  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  CGContextRelease(context);

#define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
#define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
#define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
#define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
```

[Here is the image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ4lX.png)

The error has gone however it just prints out a blank result, Anyone know why?

Comment: What are these `R`, `G`, and `B` functions being used here?

Comment: I have added more code to give you a better understanding of my issuse :)

Comment: Not sure why the macros appears as a `char *` but try adding a cast.

Comment: @rmaddy I suspect it is some obscure thing where the masking with 0xFF forces a CHAR or something?

Comment: i have ran you example and the warning is dissappeared.i have changed it a little bit.

Comment: The warning disappeared however it still dosent function the way i want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the format specifiers as follows:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"R= %3.0u", "G= 3.0u", "B= 3.0u", R(color), G(color), B(color)];
```

This function expects all the parameters which should be replaced in the first argument. The issue is the second parameter.
This is the first argument.

```
 @"R= %3.0u"
```

And the next argument should be the value to be replaced in place of **%3.0u** and the next argument is a string **"G= 3.0u"** that's why it is giving you the warning. Replace your code with this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"R= %3.0u G= %3.0u B= %3.0u", R(color), G(color), B(color)];
```

Then you are good to go. For further inquiry:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497275-stringwithformat

Comment: if u clearly see the above code posted it is [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R= %3.0u", "G= 3.0u", "B= 3.0u", R(color), G(color), B(color)]; and he specified the second argument ad string.I think u will be quite familiar with this stringwithformat method. The second argument is string thats why it is giving him the warning of char *

Comment: it is still the same :). i found the mistake and posted the answer. Please have a look on question :)

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I have added a print screen of the output on my question, it dosent print the result i need still.

Comment: I managed to find the answer!  ' _resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R= %u G= %u B= %u", R(color), G(color), B(color)];'

Comment: As per your requirement for the warning i resolved the issue :)

Comment: @rmaddy i dont know why u cant see these as three separate strings but still i can see there are three separate strings. Questions is still there and i can see that. Which u are referring thats the upper line but the warning appear on the next line which are three separate strings.And as the question was about the warning my answer perfectly solve the warning.I have run the code and solved the issue.So....

Comment: Also @rmaddy the OP's has clearly mentioned where the warning appears.
    ERROR HERE >>  _resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R= %3.0u", "G= 3.0u", "B= 3.0u", R(color), G(color), B(color)];.    These are separate strings.

Comment: My apologizes. This entire time I was looking at the printf statement which has just one string. All of my comments were based on that line.  I never noticed the stringWithFormat which clearly has extra strings. I'm sorry for wasting people's time with my oversight.

Comment: No problem @rmaddy you are a guru of iOS ;)